# Why does setting the Perl input record separator to $/="__Data__\n" not work?

Tags: perl

Why does setting the Perl input record separator to $/ = "__Data__\n" not work?

The data record is set as follows:

```
 __Data__\n
 1aaaaaaaaaa\n
 aaaaaaaaaaa\n
 aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n
 __Data__\n
 1bbbbbbbbbb\n
 bbbbbbbbbbb\n
 bbbbbbbbbbbbb\n
 __Data__\n
 1cccccccccc\n
 ccccccccccc\n
 ccccccccccccc\n
 __Data__\n
```

Here is the Perl code to access the first row of each data record...

```
$/ = "__Data__\n";

open READFILE, "<", "logA.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

while (<READFILE>)
{
   if (/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/sm)
   {
       print "$1\n";
   }
}
close(<READFILE>);
```

I get the undesirable output of:

```
__Data__
```

and not the desirable output of:

```
1aaaaaaaaaaa
1bbbbbbbbbbb
1ccccccccccc
```

Why is the input record separator `$/="__Data__";` not working? How should it work?

Comment: Is that a literal, visible "\n" in the data?

Comment: no, not literal but how its layout in the data file

Comment: Don't post code other than the code you ran. Don't post data other than the data you used. Post the output you actually got.

Comment: what part is badly formatted in this question?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene I'm still not clear about the data.  If you open logA.txt in a text editor, do you see `\n`?

Comment: Which part isn't? It says you used `"$/="Data\n"`. It says got "`Data`" for output. It says you want "`1aaaaaaaaaaa 1bbbbbbbbbbb 1ccccccccccc`" for output, the floating "`} close();`", etc. Did you read it?

Comment: @ikegami, it seem like a stackoverflow problem but when I attempt to edit it, it says __Data__

Comment: I fixed the formatting.  You have to indent code 4 spaces, no less.  Silly, I know.  So from what I understand your question is how do you avoid capturing the `__Data__` part along with everything else?

Comment: The question is why the first row of every data record is not displaying when using the input record separator of $/="__Data__\n";

Comment: It's cause you didn't put it backticks like I previously mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean backticks? Sorry if I overlook your answer...

Comment: It doesn't display them because it dies from a compilation error (`Type of arg 1 to close must be HANDLE (not <HANDLE>)`) because you used `close(<READFILE>);` instead of `close(READFILE);`

Comment: Wow, really ikegami... You mean I have to do this: $/=`__Data__\n`;

Comment: No, `[backtick]$/="__Data__\n";[/backtick]` (except using an actual backtick) to make `$/="__Data__\n";` appear correctly.

Comment: I recommend you two take this to chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat

Comment: Seriously? This is the 4th time you've asked this today. You've had more than enough help to figure this out yourself. Really

Comment: I keep getting work around answers and not answers to question.

Comment: No one is able to tell me why the perl input record separator with a value of $/="__Data__\n" does not work

Comment: Its driving me crazy and can't sleep..

Comment: Can someone please tell me why the perl input record separator with a value of $/="__Data__" is not working based on the code listed above? I don't need a work around, only a technical explanation to why its not working?

Comment: The only reason the other lines are working is because of your regex not matching the first line, $/ doesn't split and remove itself from your data, it splits and includes itself in the data, that's why you do chomp before any operations on $_ in your loop.  adding chomp before your if is sufficent, read perldoc -f chomp

Comment: MKV, thanks for putting me on the right track. After using chomp, it remove the input record separator value but still can't get the first line of each record except the first record...

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to strip out the `__Data__` part.  You want this...

```
1aaaaaaaaaa
1bbbbbbbbbb
1cccccccccc
```

...but you're getting this...

```
__Data__
1aaaaaaaaaa
1bbbbbbbbbb
1cccccccccc
```

You can use the `chomp` command to remove the end of line.  Normally this is just a newline, but `chomp` responds to whatever you set `$/` to.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $/="__Data__\n";
    open my $fh, "<", "logA.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

    while(my $record = <$fh>) {
        chomp $record;
        print $record;
    }
}
```

BTW because you changed the concept of "end of line", everything between the `__Data__` fields will be considered a single line.  If you need to split the lines up, you can use `my @lines = split "\n", $record`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    # Isolate the change to the global $/
    local $/="__Data__\n";

    open my $fh, "<", "logA.txt" or die "Unable to open file";

    while(my $record = <$fh>) {
        # Remove the __Data__ separator
        chomp $record;

        # Split the record by line
        my @lines = split /\n/, $record;

        # Empty record, skip it
        next if !@lines;

        # Print the first line of the record
        print $lines[0], "\n";
    }
}
```

I also made some general improvements to your code.  `$/` is global and will affect everything that reads files.  `local` ensures your change only happens inside the block.

I've used lexical filehandles, they automatically close themselves when they go out of scope (when the block they're declared in is done).

And I've turned on strict and warnings which will catch typos and little mistakes like `close(<READLINE>)`.

Comment: Thanks but the question remains, how do I print the first line of each record?

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene Yes, it's much better now. I've explained the changes at the end of the post as well as commented each line to explain what it does. If you were looking for just something you could paste into your existing code without understanding it, those aren't the sort of answers I like to give. If you have questions about the changes, I'll be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 2):

input.txt

```
__Data__
1aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa
__Data__
1bbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbb
__Data__
1cccccccccc
ccccccccccc
ccccccccccccc
__Data__
```

using `$/=qq{__Data__\n}`

```
perl -e 'use Data::Dumper;$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; $/=qq{__Data__\n}; open $fh,"input.txt"; print Dumper [ <$fh> ]'

$VAR1 = [
      "__Data__\n",
      "1aaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\n__Data__\n",
      "1bbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n__Data__\n",
      "1cccccccccc\nccccccccccc\nccccccccccccc\n__Data__"
    ];
```

using `$/=qq{Data}`

```
$VAR1 = [
      "__Data",
      "__\n1aaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\n__Data",
      "__\n1bbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbbb\nbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n__Data",
      "__\n1cccccccccc\nccccccccccc\nccccccccccccc\n__Data",
      "__"
    ];
```

I guess it's self explanatory.

Comment: The problem with these answers is that I have switch my thinking to fit the thinking to the new code answer rather then the answer working from my code example which makes things more complex than what it should be. From your example, I have no idea why you're using the $VAR1 and the $/=qq{__Data__\n} is not working...

Comment: First you have to get a firm grasp on what `$/` is and how does it affect file reading. `$VAR1 ..` is `Data::Dumper` output and shows how perl reads your file, record by record, in relation to `$/` value.